# Angular Resolve error on page refresh

Tags: angular

I have set up a angular resolve to get the data of a component before the component is initialized.  It might be worth mentioning that the backend is a asp net core 2 project, which is where the index.html is.

On accessing this route by the app, it loads fine. However, when I refresh the page with the resolve, it crashes giving me this error -
     **URLs requested via Http on the server must be absolute**

What I think is happening is because the resolve it attempting to load the data before anything else, it doesn't know the full URL thus crashes.

Here is my resolve code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from "../models/user";
import { UserService } from '../services/user-service';

@Injectable()
export class UserDetailResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
      return this.userService.getUser(+route.paramMap.get('id'));
  }
}
```

Here is my app component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import { UserService } from "../../services/user-service";


import { User } from "../../models/user";

@Component({
    selector: 'user-detail',
    templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-detail.component.css']
})

export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.user = this.route.snapshot.data['userDetail'];
        //this.route.paramMap
        //    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.userService.getUser(+params.get('id')))
        //    .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
    }



}
```

Here is my service code:

```
private baseUserUrl = 'api/User/'
getUser(id: number): Promise<User> {
    let url = '' + this.baseUserUrl + 'GetUserAsync?id=' + id;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(resp => resp.json() as User);
};
```

And finally, here is my routing code:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'usersearch', component: UserSearchComponent },
    { path: 'userdetail/:id', component: UserDetailComponent, resolve: { userDetail: UserDetailResolve} }
])
```

Comment: what is the complete url of your API ?

Comment: As in the domain name? @Med_Ali_Rachid

Comment: yep .. u have to give the whole URL ( http://... ) , then pass it as an argument to the http's get

Comment: But why? @Med_Ali_Rachid

Comment: because as i know , and as the error tells you  the url has to be absolute , the http's get method doesn't accept relative URL's , it doesn't know automatically that the "backend server" is in localhost.. did u got the point ?

Comment: So, how does angular work it out every other time?

Comment: u can create a settings ts file that contains your URLs base configurations..and whenever there is changes (for example the server is changed) u change it just in the settings file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156457/discussion-between-ben-donnelly-and-med-ali-rachid).